# Facebook UI and API show different permissions granted, can't re-request

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have an app that lets you schedule posts to Facebook for your Facebook Pages, among other things.

For some reason late last week, the API started showing users of my app having different permissions than the Facebook UI (Settings->Apps->(my app)).  The app was working fine for months, and suddenly stopped because of this permission change.

The users did not make any changes to the App's permissions, or their global security settings.  Facebook still shows the correct permissions for the App for the logged in user in their App settings [1].  When logged into my site, however, the API request shows none of the extended_permissions [2].  The users have not changed their FB password.  I have confirmed the app is requesting the correct user via the API.

Things I've tried:

- When I force a re-request of the extended_permissions (manage_pages, publish_stream, read_insights), it is simply ignored.
- When I add a *new* permission (manage_ads), ONLY that permission is requested in the UI.
- When the user removes the app in Facebook and re-installs, only the new permission (manage_ads) is requested.
- If I remove manage_ads from the request and the user removes and
  re-installs, no extended_permissions are asked for.
- If I make the
  user a developer/admin of my App in the Developer/App settings on FB,
  everything works as expected and the user is prompted for the correct permissions again. (and everything has been working for me, the admin of the app, this entire time)

I'm not sure what to do or how to proceed! Thank you in advance!

See screenshots here of the user's Facebook settings page and print_r of /me/permissions:

[1] https://i.stack.imgur.com/eS7Kw.png (Facebook UI in App Settings)

[2] https://i.stack.imgur.com/pZYYJ.png (Facebook API /me/permissions)

Comment: It seems like it may be some API version update from publish_stream to publish_pages --- but errors on Facebook's side of not automatically moving the permissions over, like they said they would.  Still no fix...

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29531613/facebook-api-2-3s-new-publish-pages-permission-do-i-need-it

People who granted manage_pages and publish_actions before v2.3 have automatically been granted publish_pages. ---- which isn't true.

Comment: Might have nothing to do with any of that, I believe it has to do with Facebook requiring reviewing of the App before those permissions can be granted now, starting April 30th, 2015.  https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review

Comment: Yeah, your app will have to be reviewed and approved before it can be granted the extended permissions you are asking for. Until then, only developers/admins/testers of the app will be able to use those extended permissions.

Comment: As an update, made some users Developers of the App, had them re-auth, and it now works for posting to /{page-id}/photos --- however, posting to /{page-id}/feed results in OAuthException: (#200) The user hasn't authorized the application to perform this action --- same exact token.  --- Thanks for the comment asarva!